# Prelink Error: prelink-cross: simple hello world example

Tags: c++, compilation, arm, cross-compiling, prelink

I am trying to [cross-prelink](https://www.yoctoproject.org/tools-resources/projects/cross-prelink) a simple hello world program. I use the cross-compile toolchain *arm-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu* and I am not sure if I have used the prelink-cross options correclty. I'll be glad if someone could point me to the right direction. More details about the source code on [github](https://github.com/fnbk/prelink-cross-example). Thank you.

**project directory tree**

```
|-arm-2012.03/
  |...
|-src/
  |-main.cpp
|-bin/
  |-hello
|-prelink_arm.conf
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stdout, "hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**prelink_arm.conf**

```
-l arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib 
-h arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib 
-l arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
-h arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
```

**compiling**

```
arm-2012.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -o bin_arm/hello src/main.cpp
```

**prelinking**

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin prelink --verbose --cache-file=cache/prelink_arm.cache --config-file=prelink_arm.conf --ld-library-path="arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib;arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib;" -h bin_arm/hello
```

**error message**

```
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/getent: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/POSIX_V6_ILP32_OFFBIG: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/iconv: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/sprof: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/iconvconfig: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/POSIX_V7_ILP32_OFF32: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/zdump: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/pcprofiledump: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/gencat: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/gdbserver: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/pldd: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/locale: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/localedef: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/XBS5_ILP32_OFFBIG: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/zic: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/POSIX_V7_ILP32_OFFBIG: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/rpcgen: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/makedb: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/getconf: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/XBS5_ILP32_OFF32: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/bin/POSIX_V6_ILP32_OFF32: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
prelink: bin_arm/hello: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
```

If I extract all the libraries that the executable is dependent on into a separate folder and set the links accordingly, then I still get the following error:

```
prelink: bin_arm/hello: Could not parse `/usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay, I found the solution:

I had to specify the **sysroot** and explicitly tell prelink which libraries to precompile.

The **directory structure** now looks like this:

```
|- arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/local/bin/hello
  \- /arm-none-linux-gnueabi
    \- libc
      \- lib
        \- libc-2.15.so
        |- libgcc_s.so.1
        |- ld-2.15.so
        |- ...
      |- usr
        \- local
          \- bin
            \- hello
      |- etc
        \- prelink.conf
|- Makefile
```

**prelink.conf**

```
-l /libc/lib
-h /libc/lib
```

And this is the prelink command:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin prelink --verbose --root=arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/ --cache-file=/etc/cache/prelink.cache --config-file=/etc/prelink.conf --ld-library-path="/lib;" -h /usr/local/bin/hello /lib/libc-2.15.so /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/ld-2.15.so
```

The source code can be found on github, make sure to checkout both branches 'master' and 'shared-library': https://github.com/fnbk/prelink-cross-example

Comment: binary using /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, not /home/acs/Desktop/fastboot/gcc-linaro-5.2-2015.11-1-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 as dynamic linker

Comment: How do I get prelink binary?? should I need build it form source or just apt-get install?

Comment: Hi zappy. It does not matter. You can use install it with a package manager (apt-get) or build it from source.

Comment: prelink binary installed by package manager doesn't have --root option. So i choose to compile the source. still I am facing lots of error while prelinking a  Qt binary for ARM like " Could not prelink /lib/libpthread.so.0 because its dependency /lib/libc.so.6 could not be prelinked" etc... Could you please Help me to find the reason ?

Comment: @zappy where did you get the source from? I'm getting the same error about `--root` option. Thanks and sorry for posting on this old thread.

Comment: @ramtheconqueror , it was just a PATH issue , giving absolute path to all linking libraries solved my problem, I don't remember from where I got the source , But surely some version of prelink had some issues. Better try with another version of source

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to use:
Full path to lib folder here:

**prelink_arm.conf**

```
-l arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib     
-h arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib     
-l arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib  
-h arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
```

And here + add $PATH to PATH variable:
**prelinking**

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH prelink --verbose  \
--cache-file=cache/prelink_arm.cache --config-file=prelink_arm.conf \
--ld-library-path="arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib;arm-2012.03/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib;" \
-h bin_arm/hello
```

Actually all of these errors is pointing you on:

> Could not parse /usr/local/sbin//prelink-rtld: **error while loading shared libraries: ld-linux.so.3**

If the first 2 notes will not help, you may try to:

- find/download `ld-linux.so.3`
- set `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH_TO_LD_LINUX_SO_3:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- or add it with  `--ld-library-path=` options, as it already done for other libs

it will add custom search path to your env.